# Discard changes on EditLabel wxtreectrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a TreeCtrl where the user is able to edit the label of an item.
However, if the user presses enter when the input is empty, then label is should be set to its former state. I am able to accomplish this, but with a bug.

This is the "workflow"

Label shows 'item'

1. User starts to edit label
2. User inputs ''
3. User presses enter
4. Label shows ''
5. User starts to edit label
6. User changes nothing, inputs ''
7. User presses enter
8. Label shows 'item'

**Code example**

```
def on_rename(self, event):
    treeItemId = self.tree.GetSelection()
    self.tree.EditLabel(treeItemId)

def on_rename_end(self, event):
    name = event.GetLabel()
    treeItemId = self.tree.GetSelection()
    pydata = self.tree.GetPyData(treeItemId)
    if len(name) <= 0:
        # pydata[1] == 'item'
        self.tree.SetItemText(treeItemId, pydata[1]) 
    else:
        dostuff()
        set_new_pydata()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my own answer

```
if len(name) <= 0:
    event.Veto()
```